# How should I insert & retrieve lists of data to & from an SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, database

I have 3 lists, each one contains all the data of one column in the SQL table. All of the list are the same length. This is how I need to insert the data into the table:

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |      C      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | listA[0]   | listB[0]    | listC[0]    |
| 2 | listA[1]   | listB[1]    | listC[1]    |
| 3 | listA[2]   | listB[2]    | listC[2]    |
| n | listA[n]   | listB[n]    | listC[n]    |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'm using Python. I have all the lists, but I'm not sure what's the best way to insert the data into the SQL table.

I will later need to retrieve the data by matching a query to the `A` column data and searching for a match. If there's a match, I will need to get all the row data, and create an object with the 3 properties:
`A = listA[x], B = listB[x], C = listC[x]`

I've been told I should use dictionaries in Python to do that, but I'm not sure if that's better.

My question is, based on the way I'm going to use this SQL database, how should I insert these lists of data into the table, and how should I represent the data when I insert it and later when I retrieve it from the table?

First I thought to just insert all the `listA` elements to column `A`, and so on with `B` and `C`. But maybe it's not a good way to do that since it's not the logical way to represent the data (lists of all `A` properties, `B`'s and `C`'s), and since I will later need to represent the data differently, I should insert it this way too.

Comment: The last thing you want to do is store lists.  I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @DanBracuk What should I store the data in instead of lists?

Answer (score 1):

You usually insert data on a row-by-row basis, not column-by-column, so it's probably easiest to [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the three lists first...

```
>>> listA = [1, 2, 3]
>>> listB = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> listC = ['i', 'ii', 'iii']
>>> zip(listA, listB, listC)
[(1, 'a', 'i'), (2, 'b', 'ii'), (3, 'c', 'iii')]
```

...then you can iterate the result of that with...

```
for row in zip(listA, listB, listC):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?, ?)', row)
```

If the lists are huge, you may want to use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead...

```
from itertools import izip

for row in izip(listA, listB, listC):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?, ?)', row)
```

The exact method for inserting the data into the DB depends on which DB backend you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
```

creating the table

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE mydata (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, A, B, C)')
```

inserting

```
db.execute('INSERT INTO mydata (A, B, C) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
    ('testA', 'testB', 'testC')
)    
db.commit()
```

retrieving

```
result = db.execute('SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE A = ?', 
    ('testA',)
)
print result.fetchall()
```

Output:

```
[(1, u'testA', u'testB', u'testC')]
```